# Issue on view page source of HTML tag data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have rendering some data from my express to ejs as HTMl tag format. It is showing properly in the ejs template page and web page. But when i am searching for page source it is encoded to unescape. Is there any solution where I can get the same HTML tag data in my page source.

Actual Data : Cleaning Services in Palm Jumeirah,
Dubai - Suit your needs & Budget\n\nHelpsters cleaning services is a professional
 provider of high quality cleaning services across Palm Jumeirah, Dubai. We have quickly become **Dubai’
s preferred cleaning service**, with over 1000 happy customers served to date, it’s easy to see why cus
tomers stick with **Helpsters** when ordering weekly, or monthly cleanings.

> \n\n
>
> Special Prices for Regular Customers.
>
> \
>   n
>
> Special Weekly and Monthly Packages.
>
> \n
>
> Enjoy trustworthy and hassle-free cleaning, everytime and anytime.
>
> \n
>
> \n
>
> Profession
>   al Filipino Cleaners.
>
> \n
>
> Easy Online Booking & 24/7 Customer Service
>   .
>
> \n\nWhether it is a luxury apa
>   rtment, a residential or an office space in Palm Jumeirah, Dubai, we are able to meet your cleaning needs. We are de
>   dicated to leaving every home or office squeaky clean every time! Forget the hassles of keeping your property clean
>   and maintaining a full time cleaning staff. Just book our 
>   **cleaning services in Palm Jumeirah**, Dubai & we will take care of rest.
> We also do <
>   strong>house cleaning, **office cleaning**, **carpet c
>   leaning** and **deep cleaning**.
>
> \n

In view page source its converted to unescape of this html.

Comment: Can you share any of your code?

Comment: Please post the contents of your EJS template for us to examine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For escaping the value correctly use
**<%= data[0].description%>**

If you want to allow HTML to be rendered, then you want an "unescaped" value. To do that use the following:
**<%- data[0].description%>**

All I did was replace the equal (=) with a dash (-).